# Why isn't an Expect-CT violation report sent when I use a certificate generated with Burp Suite?

Tags: http-proxy, certificate-transparency

I wanted to test the Expect-CT security header. So I searched for sites and found that LinkedIn uses the Expect-CT header:

```
Expect-CT: max-age=86400, report-uri="https://www.linkedin.com/platform-telemetry/ct"
```

I configured my Chrome with Burp Suite so that it would use a certificate issued by PortSwigger Burp Suite, which is not logged in public CT logs. I then accessed linkedin.com.

Since the Expect-CT header was served the browser should query CT logs, and since the certificate isn't recorded in CT logs it should generate a report to the report-URI. But I didn't observe any violation report being sent there.

Is it because PortSwigger Burp Suite CA is configured to always trust in system?

Answer (score 4):

Certificate Transparency (CT) does not apply to non-public root Certificate Authorities. CT only validates that certificates issues by trusted public CAs were issued legitimately.

Your Burp Suite certificate is configured on your system as a trusted root certificate and no CT policy will therefore be applied to it.

The [Mozilla MDN page on Expect-CT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expect-CT) also explicitly states this behaviour:

> Root CAs manually added to the trust store override and suppress Expect-CT reports/enforcement.